# How to extract the RGB values from the image and calculate its output?

Tags: julia, pluto.jl

I have a function where I have got the RGB-values from the image and calculate the mean value for each pixel,  how can I approach this problem?

```
function RGB2G_mean(img::Matrix{RGB{T}}) where T<:Fractional
    # get RGB-values from img
     # R,G,B=...

     output =
    return Gray.(output)
end
```

Comment: You can access a particular color of a RGB value `x` with `x.r`, `x.g`, `x.b`. Dot access is convenient syntax for `getproperty(x, :r)`. You can broadcast that over an entire `Matrix{RGB{T}}` to get a `Matrix{T}` of a particular color: `getproperty.(img, :r)`. You can get access to a `mean` function via `using Statistics`. Still, if `T` is an integer type, you'll have to worry about overflow by summing, I'm not sure if `mean` guards against this.

Answer (score 2):

```
julia> using Colors, ColorVectorSpace, FixedPointNumbers, Statistics

julia> a = rand(RGB{N0f8}, 4)
4-element Array{RGB{N0f8},1} with eltype RGB{N0f8}:
 RGB{N0f8}(0.588,0.459,0.529)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.592,0.247,0.408)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.31,0.18,0.396)
 RGB{N0f8}(0.235,1.0,0.675)

julia> mean(a)
RGB{Float64}(0.43137254901960786,0.4715686274509804,0.5019607843137255)
```

To address a concern of BatWannaBe in the comments, yes, `mean` guards against overflow.